# I can't debug C in VSCode/CodeBlocks or Any IDE

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

This is my launch.json

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb32.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

**It was GDB.exe here earlier, But it said it couldn't find it , Even I couldn't find it..
So I put gdb32.exe as i was able to find that out , But it still didn't debug anything**

i am fed up of this problem now...

**Code Blocks says Please specify executable path,It can't be found**

Please help, Thanks

Comment: If your motivation is to debug a c/c++ code in Code::Blocks just like using gdb, you can use their in-built debug tool. You can find some basic guideline here:  https://www.dummies.com/programming/c/how-to-use-the-codeblocks-debugger-with-c-programming/

Comment: @AnkushPandit That's what I can't do buddy

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks can be installed without MinGW, which is okay as MinGW-w64 is much better maintained. But MinGW-w64 needs to be installed separately.

You can download a standalone MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ and the site also explains on how to add this compiler and debugger to the settings.